# regex to select match from string issue

Tags: regex, string, c#-4.0

**why regex return multi value for the match?**

See the following code, it should only return one result. why there are two?

```
e.g 
Match m = Regex.Match("[Red] #,0.00 \"Ex\"", @"^\[(RED|GREEN|ORANGE)\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            if (m.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.Groups.Count);    
                Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
                Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("No match");

========Result===============
2
[Red]
Red
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a single match `m`, which has a single capturing group.  `m.Groups[0]` is always the entire match.  `m.Groups[1]` is the first capture, etc..

If you want to see all matches, you can do this:

```
foreach (Match m in regex.Matches (input))
   Console.WriteLine (m.Value);
```

Comment: but the werid things is. if i do this "^\[(RED)\]",  will match "RED" and "[RED]", if only "^\[RED\]" then i will only match "[RED]"...why????

Comment: `^[(RED)]` is a character class at the begining of the line.  It is equivilent to `^[DER()]`.  Square brackets mean to match any *one* of the characters inside.  It will match any one of these characters: `()DER`.  That's why in your case, you need to escape the `[` and `[` like this: `^\[(RED)\]`.